# How to fix broken formats when exporting R output to a TXT file?

Tags: r, performance, formatting, format

First of all, I apologize for asking a silly question because I'm relatively new to R.

I've been trying for hours to fix this issue but I can't get it right. I've also tried to search some relevant topics on Google, but to no avail. I tried to create a function in R which can perform [a Monte Carlo simulation which can't be properly handled in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38891165/3397819). Here are the two functions I created:

```
ZoomRNG1 <- function(n,Px1,Px2,Py1,Py2)
{
  sink("DataZoomRNG1.txt")
  for(i in 1:n)
  {
    repeat
    {
      x = runif(1)
      y = runif(1)
      if(x > Px1 & x < Px2)
      {
        if(y > Py1 & y < Py2)
        {
          cat(i, x, y, "\n", sep="\t", append=TRUE);
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
  sink()
}
```

and

```
ZoomRNG2 <- function(n,Px1,Px2,Py1,Py2)
{
  logFile = "DataZoomRNG2.txt"
  for(i in 1:n)
  {
    repeat
    {
      x = runif(1)
      y = runif(1)
      if(x > Px1 & x < Px2)
      {
        if(y > Py1 & y < Py2)
        {
          cat(i, x, y, file=logFile, append=TRUE, "\n", sep="\t");
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Both functions work fine and the plot of ZoomRNG1 function outputs (1,000 data for each random variables `x` and `y`) in Excel is shown in the figure below:

[image]

But the problems are

1. Both functions run relatively slow on my machine. **OS:** Windows 10 Pro 64-bit; **System Model:** HP Pro 3330 MT; **Processor:** Intel Core i3-2120 CPU @ 3.30GHz (4 CPUs); **Memory:** 4 GB.
2. Some of their outputs' format are broken, for example

```
389     0.5067888       0.5064327   
390     0.50462 0.5083072   
391     0.5040369       0.5075297   
392     0.5094  0.5064151   
393     0.5068058       0.5041317   
394     0.5073923       0.5002383
```

As one can see above, the formats of line 390 and 392 are broken (some of other lines are broken, too). How does one fix this issue? Also, is there a way to make both functions run faster? Something like (maybe?) writing the outputs of the function in array/ vector first and then exporting the result to an external file like I usually do when writing the program in VBA.

Comment: Regarding the output format, you can force the number of decimal places. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443687/formatting-decimal-places-in-r), for methods of doing that

Comment: Maybe simplify it as: `write.table(data.frame(
    x = runif(n, Px1, Px2),
    y = runif(n, Py1, Py2)),
    "DataZoomRNG1.txt", sep = "\t")`

Comment: @Acarbalacar Issue no 2 seems to be fixed. Perhaps you wanna write an answer for your suggestion?

Comment: @zx8754 Yes, I'm also aware of this way: `x = runif(n, Px1, Px2), y = runif(n, Py1, Py2)`, but is the probability distribution of both ways (my way and your way) still the same? Will the both outputs follow the same distribution?

Comment: Yes, any particular reason they would not be?

Comment: @Axeman Dunno, my intuition seems to think so. Is there a theory to support that claim?

Comment: `set.seed(42); for (i in 1:5) print(runif(1)); set.seed(42); runif(5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simplify looped functions to:

```
write.table(data.frame(x = runif(n, Px1, Px2),
                       y = runif(n, Py1, Py2)),
            "DataZoomRNG1.txt", sep = "\t")
```

Regarding "broken format", it is not broken, it is tab separated.
[image]

Avoid Excel copy paste, use R plot instead, see example:

```
n = 100
Px1 = 10
Px2 = 20
Py1 = 5
Py2 = 7

set.seed(42)
df1 <- data.frame(x = runif(n, Px1, Px2),
                  y = runif(n, Py1, Py2))

plot(df1)
```

As @Roland demosntrated with set.seed, `forloop` and `runif` output should be the same:

```
set.seed(42)
for (i in 1:5) print(runif(1))
# [1] 0.914806
# [1] 0.9370754
# [1] 0.2861395
# [1] 0.8304476
# [1] 0.6417455

set.seed(42)
runif(5)
# [1] 0.9148060 0.9370754 0.2861395 0.8304476 0.6417455
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and yes, it's really fast. But how do I ensure that the output of your way will follow the same distribution as the output of my way? Do you have a mathematical reasoning to support the claim? (+1)

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 as Roland showed in the comments, `for loop`and `runif` on its own will give you the same result?

Comment: Regarding the broken format, when I tried to copy the output in Notepad and then paste it to Excel, it wasn't separated properly so I thought it's broken

Comment: Seeing from the chart, it seems there's no different but I haven't done any fitting test yet to check it.